# How can I prevent function inside of forEach loop from being called more than once? (For the most part it repeats predictably)

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a function included in a forEach loop that repeats unpredictably

```
function setColorColumns(id) {
  getID = id.replace("#", "");
  color_ranges.forEach((item) => {
  colorRangeDivs += `<div class="col ${item.colorGroup.toLowerCase()}" title="${item.colorGroup}" style="background:${item.colorGroup.toLowerCase()}">`;
  colorRangeDivs += `<label for="chk_${getID}_${item.colorGroup.toLowerCase()}">`;
  colorRangeDivs += `<input type="checkbox" id="chk_${getID}_${item.colorGroup.toLowerCase()}"></label></div>\n`;
  });
  return colorRangeDivs;
}

namedColors.forEach((item) => {
  colorDiv = setColorColumns(item.hex);
  colorTable1 = `<div class="color_table_row"><div class="col2"     style="background:${item.hex}">`;
  colorTable2 = `${item.color} (${item.hex})</div>`;
  colorTable3 = `</div>`;
  colorTable += `${colorTable1}${colorTable2}${colorDiv}${colorTable3}`;
});
```

The setColorColumns() function creates the checkboxes and that's what repeats for every iteration. If anything, I would think the entire row would repeat, but obviously I'm missing something...

Here's a CodePen version: https://codepen.io/NoahBoddy/pen/WNpzMbV

Comment: forEach will run your function exactly once for every item in the array. It is not unpredictable. 

It looks as if you are running in a web browser, so I am guessing it is the event that runs your code that is triggered more than once.

Comment: second parameter in `forEach` loop gives you `index`. You can use index to call the `function` once like this. namedColors.forEach((item,i) => {
if(i == 0){
  colorDiv = setColorColumns(item.hex)}}

Comment: I tried applying it here: https://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/eYvMMOy 
and here: https://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/gOmevVO
But I'm not applying it correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `index` inside the `foreach` loop to solve this issue.

```
// FOREACH
namedColors.forEach((item, index) => {
  if(index === 0) {
    colorDiv = setColorColumns(item.hex);
  }
  colorTable1 = `<div class="color_table_row"><div class="col2" style="background:${item.hex}">`;
  colorTable2 = `${item.color} (${item.hex})</div>`;
  // this is the line that's getting me in trouble
  colorTable3 = `</div>`;
  colorTable += `${colorTable1}${colorTable2}${colorDiv}${colorTable3}`;
  
});
```

Comment: I think you're on to something, but that only returns one row: https://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/gOmevVO

Comment: @user3561924 i've updated my code. Please check now. Hope this'll work.